# in jmeter:java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find the TestPlan class

Tags: java, jmeter, runtimeexception

I am trying to run jmx script using java code. but when I tried to run the code it is showing me testplan does not exist. I checked here with this question [/jmeter-could-not-find-the-testplan-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758705/jmeter-could-not-find-the-testplan-class) and I checked my jmx file. It's proprerly formatted.

Here is my jmx file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="2.8" jmeter="2.13 r1665067">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="first try" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1455186838000</longProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1455186838000</longProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="speciality" enabled="true">
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">localhost</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">8080</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">JmeterJson/speciality</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <hashTree>
          <RegexExtractor guiclass="RegexExtractorGui" testclass="RegexExtractor" testname="Regular Expression Extractor" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.useHeaders">false</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.refname">names</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.regex">(dentist|cardio)</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.template">$1$</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.default">NONE</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.match_number">-1</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Sample.scope">all</stringProp>
          </RegexExtractor>
          <hashTree/>
          <DebugPostProcessor guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="DebugPostProcessor" testname="Debug PostProcessor" enabled="true">
            <boolProp name="displayJMeterProperties">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="displayJMeterVariables">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="displaySamplerProperties">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="displaySystemProperties">false</boolProp>
          </DebugPostProcessor>
          <hashTree/>
        </hashTree>
        <ForeachController guiclass="ForeachControlPanel" testclass="ForeachController" testname="ForEach Controller" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="ForeachController.inputVal">names</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="ForeachController.returnVal">name</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="ForeachController.useSeparator">true</boolProp>
        </ForeachController>
        <hashTree>
          <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="${name}" enabled="true">
            <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
              <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
            </elementProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">localhost</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">8080</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">JmeterJson/names?speciality=${name}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
          </HTTPSamplerProxy>
          <hashTree>
            <DebugPostProcessor guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="DebugPostProcessor" testname="Debug PostProcessor" enabled="true">
              <boolProp name="displayJMeterProperties">false</boolProp>
              <boolProp name="displayJMeterVariables">true</boolProp>
              <boolProp name="displaySamplerProperties">true</boolProp>
              <boolProp name="displaySystemProperties">false</boolProp>
            </DebugPostProcessor>
            <hashTree/>
            <RegexExtractor guiclass="RegexExtractorGui" testclass="RegexExtractor" testname="Regular Expression Extractor" enabled="true">
              <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.useHeaders">false</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.refname">times</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.regex">(deepak|kk|kumar|bs)</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.template">$1$</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.default">NONE</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="RegexExtractor.match_number">-1</stringProp>
            </RegexExtractor>
            <hashTree/>
          </hashTree>
          <ForeachController guiclass="ForeachControlPanel" testclass="ForeachController" testname="ForEach Controller" enabled="true">
            <stringProp name="ForeachController.inputVal">times</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="ForeachController.returnVal">time</stringProp>
            <boolProp name="ForeachController.useSeparator">true</boolProp>
          </ForeachController>
          <hashTree>
            <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="${time}" enabled="true">
              <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
                <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
              </elementProp>
              <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">localhost</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">8080</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
              <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
              <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
              <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
              <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">JmeterJson/appointments?things=${time}</stringProp>
              <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
              <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
              <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
              <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
              <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
              <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
              <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
            </HTTPSamplerProxy>
            <hashTree>
              <DebugPostProcessor guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="DebugPostProcessor" testname="Debug PostProcessor" enabled="true">
                <boolProp name="displayJMeterProperties">false</boolProp>
                <boolProp name="displayJMeterVariables">true</boolProp>
                <boolProp name="displaySamplerProperties">true</boolProp>
                <boolProp name="displaySystemProperties">false</boolProp>
              </DebugPostProcessor>
              <hashTree/>
            </hashTree>
          </hashTree>
        </hashTree>
        <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>true</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>false</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>false</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
        <CSVDataSet guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="CSVDataSet" testname="CSV Data Set Config" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="filename">specialist</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="fileEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="variableNames"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="delimiter">,</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="quotedData">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="recycle">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="stopThread">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="shareMode">shareMode.all</stringProp>
        </CSVDataSet>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

here is my TestPlan class:

```
package main.java.test;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

public class TestPlan {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    StandardJMeterEngine jmeter=new StandardJMeterEngine();

    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/Users/vihang_shah01/Desktop/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/jmeter.properties");
    JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("/Users/vihang_shah01/Desktop/apache-jmeter-2.13");
    JMeterUtils.initLogging();
    JMeterUtils.initLocale();

    try {
        SaveService.loadProperties();

        FileInputStream file=new FileInputStream("/Users/vihang_shah01/Desktop/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/firstTry.jmx");

        HashTree hash=new HashTree(file);

        file.close();

        jmeter.configure(hash);
        jmeter.run();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }





}





}
```

This is my exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find the TestPlan class!
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.configure(StandardJMeterEngine.java:171)
    at main.java.com.infy.test.TestPlan.main(TestPlan.java:32)
```

plz can anyone tell me what this error and how to resolve it?thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I got my mistake. I have to load the jmx fie in SAve service method. line number 32 should be like **HashTree hash=SaveService.loadTree(file);**
instead of *HashTree hash=new HashTree(file);..thank you*

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to open the jmx file in jmeter? 
The problem was with this line #126.

```
          <stringPropname="HTTPSampler.path">JmeterJson/appointments?things=${time}</stringProp>
```

It should be

```
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">JmeterJson/appointments?things=${time}</stringProp>
```

---

Just curious - Why do you want to run the JMeter test using Java?
What do you like to achieve?

You can use Ant/Maven to run JMeter tests if you want to run programmatically.
You can see the detailed steps here: http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-continuous-performance-testing-part1/

Comment: it's just copy paste problem.it's actually in the second format u mention.and I tried to run using jmeter. it's working.but via java code it's not. I have to merge it with GUI so I m using java code

Comment: Hi, You seem to be adding a link to a website that has subscriptions. It looks like you are trying to get more views on the site. Note that doing so might increase suspicion among the members of the community that may lead to the suspension of your account. Refer this [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294124/4099593). I am writing this comment to warn you beforehand. Regards.

Comment: @BhargavRao, Nothing like that. It is my blog. I just wanted to let the OP know if there are other ways to invoke the JMeter test. It does not require any subscription / I do not have any ads.

Comment: @VinothS Just a friendly check. Also go through this http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion to see how to include your own blog post in the answer.

Comment: No problem. Another useful read [What signifies "Good" self promotion? (or: Self Promotion Part Infinity)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212) (Hope you don't mind me throwing up links at you)