# jmeter non-gui test plan with source address spoofing

Tags: jmeter, command-line-interface, spoofing

1- I am using the jmeter gui to build a simple test plan with **variable source IPs (spoofing IP source)**.
***The test works fine*** from gui mode with the following config:
(secondary IPs are configured accordingly)

[image]

[image]

[image]

2- Now I would like to do the same from the non-gui mode.
I "saved as" the test plan from the gui into HTTP-Request.jmx file (as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758705/jmeter-could-not-find-the-testplan-class))

I have noticed that the jmx file contains the source IP variable created in the gui **but no mention of the CSV file from which to read the values.**
I have tried the follwing commands:

```
jmeter -n -t HTTP-Request.jmx  -j testplan_01.log
```

> Creating summariser 
>   Created the tree successfully using
>   HTTP-Request.jmx Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Could not find the TestPlan class!

Tested the option **-p** which seem to indicate parameter file.

```
jmeter -n -t HTTP-Request.jmx -p source-ip.txt -j testplan_01.log
```

> Creating summariser 
>   Created the tree successfully using
>   HTTP-Request.jmx Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Could not find the TestPlan class!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This [article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter) has detail procedure on "IP Spoofing".

Comment: Thanks Adrian for your reply. One of my references to configure IP spoofing (GUI mode) was the series of articles from that site. That's what I have explained in (1), my issue is do that with the non-gui mode (2).

Comment: Read in another post, that this is fixed by bin/jmeter.sh +the parameters you want.

Answer (score 0):

Possible you incorrect save your test plan. Try to open your flume_http_test.jmx i guess it contains only http request element without test plan element. Try to save your test with test plan element selected.

[image]